# How to map after melt?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using pandas, I load some data that I get in a "pivoted" format. Thus I would like to first unpivot the data, and then apply some transformations. Most notably encode a binary variable.

The strategy that I have is to use `melt` to unpivot, and then create a new column, by using boolean operators on one of the old columns. I tried the below code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,10],[2,50,100]],columns=['ID','X1','X2'])
df2 = pd.melt(df
              ,id_vars=['ID']
              ,value_vars=['X1','X2']
              ,var_name='var'
              ,value_name='value')

df2['ID-bool'] = df.ID == 1
print(df2['ID-bool'])
```

Unfortunately, it gives an unexpected result since `melt` seems to do something funky with the index. Only the 1st and 2nd rows in the dataframe has got boolean values, and row 3 and 4 (that `melt` created) gets NaN instead.

```
0     True
1    False
2      NaN
3      NaN
Name: ID-bool, dtype: object
```

How should I do it to get my expected result? I don't wish to add the new column before the `melt`.

Comment: shouldnt it be df2['ID-bool'] = df2.ID == 1 ?

Comment: shouldnot it be `df2.ID == 1` and not `df.ID==1` ? since `df` has just 2 rows so you get NaNs for the rest of the 2, or are you trying to do something which we are missing?

Comment: go to the corner and feel ashamed of yourself :-)

Comment: GAAAH! Thank you for pointing it out. I just noticed it myself, and thought I would come back and close the question before anyone noticed....  But you beat me to it. What is more proper - to accept the answer or close the question?

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for closing it! I can't close it myself since I'm lacking rep, but am voting for closure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `df2` instead of `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,10],[2,50,100]],columns=['ID','X1','X2'])
df2 = pd.melt(df
              ,id_vars=['ID']
              ,value_vars=['X1','X2']
              ,var_name='var'
              ,value_name='value')

df2['ID-bool'] = df2.ID == 1 # Changed df.ID to df2.ID
print(df2)
```

```
   ID var  value  ID-bool
0   1  X1      5     True
1   2  X1     50    False
2   1  X2     10     True
3   2  X2    100    False
```